# Python, mock that was imported with relative path

Tags: python, patch

Have you faced the problem, how to mock that was imported by a relative path? Python.
I don't want to use an absolute path, because all my modules are in the same folder.

More precisely:

The tested file:

```
from ..some_module import something   # <- the relative path
```

The test:

```
@patch(‘test_libs.some_path.some_module.something.method’)
def test_something()
. . . .
```

Such a patch accepts an absolute path only, and doesn't mock the class, imported relatively.
I've googled, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Are you sure you're having the issue when patching `long_path.something.method` and importing `something`? I'd expect that to work. I'd expect trouble if you were patching `long_path.something` itself. Something to try might be to change the tested code to import only the *module* and not the class. Try `from . import some_module` then use `some_module.something` later.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out that the reason was not in the relative path. Sorry for the disturbance, you can close the topic.